# role-based page views with angular and node

Tags: node.js, security, angularjs

In my app, I have a main page for admins, who should be able to perform admin actions.

I know that all server calls need to be properly authenticated and all that. Nevertheless I'd like to reduce security problems on the client side as much as possible. Finally, it's just javascript on the client.

So how do I design different views role-based on the client?
For example, is it a good idea to have different angular base templates for the app as an admin and as a regular user? I feel nervous sharing the same template, and then doing things like "if user.role==admin" on the client...

What is a good approach:
I am using passport.

```
passport_options =
  successRedirect: '/dashboard'
  failureRedirect: '/'
  failureFlash: true
```

but this seems not to allow conditional statements (e.g. successRedirect: if user.role="admin"....)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ternary operation (?:)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a), which is a practice that has some [bad vibes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#.3F%3a_in_style_guidelines) among some

```
successRedirect: user.role == 'admin' ? '/dashboad' : '/notAdmin'
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but I have more than two roles, so I ended up using a custom callback as documented in the passport docs http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/